# Show values in bar chart using pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have developed a tool to statistically analyze bugs and calculate metrics. I am using pyplot to generate graphs for the same. For bar chart, I have values on the Y axis and names of QA members on X- axis. So for each qa there is a bar. This is the code I am using right now -

```
 xco = []
 for i in range(len(labels)):
    xco.append(labels[i] + "-" + str(metrics[i]))
 plt.xticks(ind, xco)
```

labels is an array of names and metrics is an array of corresponding values.
However this seems kind of hacky. Moreover, this gives my list of qa appended with individual values at the bottom of the graph. What I want is the names of the qa as x axis co-ordinators and values on top of each bar. Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: The solution is given in http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/barchart_demo.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want text on the top and bottom of the bars, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423445/how-can-i-display-text-over-columns-in-a-bar-chart-in-matplotlib/7423575#7423575) answer, where you create an array 'names' that goes on the top and another array that is displayed for the tickmarks, such as:

```
plt.xticks(ind+width/2., ('a', 'b','c', 'd', 'e'))
```