# Displaying totals above stacked bars in barchart: matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am just starting out with matplotlib.pyplot and am a little stuck.

Using the example in the matpltlib.pyplot documentation, I have created a stacked bar chart [image] using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 7
OECD = (242, 244, 255, 263, 269, 276, 285)
NonOECD = (282, 328, 375, 417, 460, 501, 535)
Sum = ('524', '572', '630', '680', '729', '777', '820')
ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.5

p1 = plt.bar(ind, NonOECD, width, color = 'r')
p2 = plt.bar(ind, OECD, width, color = 'b', bottom = NonOECD)

plt.ylabel('Quadrillion Btu')
plt.title('World Total Energy Consumption 2010 - 2040')
plt.xticks(ind+width/2., ('2010', '2015', '2020', '2025', '2030', '2035', '2040'))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 1001, 200))
plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0]), ('Non - OECD', 'OECD'), loc = 2, frameon = 'false')
plt.tick_params(top = 'off', bottom = 'off', right = 'off')
plt.grid(axis = 'y', linestyle = '-')

plt.show()
```

However I want to display the totals on top of the bars and I cannot quite work out how. I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423445/how-can-i-display-text-over-columns-in-a-bar-chart-in-matplotlib?rq=1) but am having issues:

```
for ii,rect in enumerate(p1):
    h1 = rect.get_height()
for ii,rect in enumerate(p2):
    h2 = rect.get_height()
    height = 
    plt.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., height, '%s'% (Sum[ii]), ha = 'center', va='bottom')
```

If I use `height = h1` I get [image]; if I use `height = h2` I get [image]; if I use `height = h1 + h2` I get [image].

What I want is these numbers sitting directly on above the second (blue) bar [like the 524 on the 2010 bar in my 1st attempt]. Am I missing something really obvious?

As always, any help would be much appreciated!
Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
for r1,r2 in zip(p1,p2):
    h1 = r1.get_height()
    h2 = r2.get_height()
    plt.text(r1.get_x()+r1.get_width()/2., h1+h2, '%s'% (h1+h2), ha = 'center', va='bottom')
```