# How to display y-bar values in the bar chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-science

Hello friends I am creating a bar chart using `seaborn` or `matplotlib`. I make a successful graph, but I don't know how to display y bar values on the plot. Please give me suggestion and different techniques to display y-bar values on the plot.

Please help me to solve the question.

Thank you

```py
plt.figure(figsize = (10,5))
sns.countplot(x='subject',data=udemy,hue='is_paid')
```

[image: img]

Comment: [Seaborn: countplot() with frequencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179122/seaborn-countplot-with-frequencies) I find this answer to be very helpful

Comment: See the autolabel function in [this example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I display text over columns in a bar chart in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423445/how-can-i-display-text-over-columns-in-a-bar-chart-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately countplot in seaborn doesn't allow both x and y values to be passed, only one can be passed per plot.

Have you tried a different chart?
e.g. plt.bar() and setting the xticks and yticks to the values you want?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** You need customized auto label mechanism.

First let's make it clear. If you mean by

> I don't know how to display y bar values on the plot

- that *on bars* (inner), then this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19919397/10452700) can be helpful.
- that *on top of bars* (outer), except for this answer for [seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179122/seaborn-countplot-with-frequencies), there are some auto label solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423445/how-can-i-display-text-over-columns-in-a-bar-chart-in-matplotlib) you can use it as well as [this example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html). Recently if you install the new matpotlib v. `3.4.0` you can use `bar_label()`[Ref.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_label_demo.html).

I can also offer you my approach inspired by this [matplotlib documenetation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html) using manual adjustment for the best fit to print value/text over bars in the bar chart using `matplotlib` in form of function:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def bar_plot(ax, data, colors=None, total_width=0.8, single_width=1, legend=True):
    

    # Check if colors where provided, otherwhise use the default color cycle
    if colors is None:
        colors = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']

    # Number of bars per group
    n_bars = len(data)

    # The width of a single bar
    bar_width = total_width / n_bars

    # List containing handles for the drawn bars, used for the legend
    bars = []

    # Iterate over all data
    for i, (name, values) in enumerate(data.items()):
        # The offset in x direction of that bar
        x_offset = (i - n_bars / 2) * bar_width + bar_width / 2

        # Draw a bar for every value of that type
        for x, y in enumerate(values):
            bar = ax.bar(x + x_offset, y, width=bar_width * single_width, color=colors[i % len(colors)])

        # Add a handle to the last drawn bar, which we'll need for the legend
        bars.append(bar[0])

    # Draw legend if we need
    if legend:
        ax.legend(bars, data.keys())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Usage example:
    data = {
        "False": [100.16,  30.04, 50.04, 120.19],
        "True": [1100.08,  600.06, 650.06, 1050.17],
        #"RMSE":[0.39,  0.19, 0.20, 0.44,  0.45,  0.26],
            }

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
    
    y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
    for i, v in enumerate(data['False']):
        plt.text(y_pos[i] - 0.35, v + 10.213, str(v))

    for i, v in enumerate(data['True']):
        plt.text(y_pos[i] + 0.05, v + 10.213, str(v))


    #plt.rc('font', **font)
    bar_plot(ax, data, total_width=.8, single_width=.9)
    #font = font_manager.FontProperties(family='Comic Sans MS', weight='bold', style='normal', size=16)
    font = {'family' : 'normal',
            'weight' : 'bold',
            'size'   : 15,
             'family':'Times New Roman'}
    #font = {'family':'Times New Roman', 'weight' :'normal','size':15}
    
    ax.set_xticklabels( ('0',' ','Business Finance',' ','Graphic Design',' ', 'Musical Instruments',' ', 'Web Development') , rotation=45, ha="right")#, **font )
    #ax.set_yticklabels( data['MSE'] ,**font )
    ax.set_ylabel('Count  ')#, **font)
    ax.set_xlabel('Subject  ')#, **font)
    ax.set_title('Figure 10/ Table 6 for is_paid')#, **font)
    #ax.legend().set_visible(False)
    plt.ylim((0.0, 1500.0))
    plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: img]